# NSLocalizedString within a framework gets values from external bundle

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

While developing a framework, i have a project with a `framework` target and a `single view application` target.

I use the single view app to test the framework.

I've created 2 `Localizable.strings` files, one in each target.

When I run the single view app, that loads the framework, code in classes from the framework that invoke `NSLocalizedString` gets values from the localization file of the other target, the single view app....

How do I allow localization in the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the bundle for your `NSLocalizableString` like you can see in this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1418095-nslocalizedstring .

If you're specifying the bundle, make sure you have the same Localizable files in the Single view app as you have in the framework, otherwise it won't be considered to avoid weird multi-language behavior in your app.
This explained in this thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49909?answerId=147858022#147858022

I hope that answers your question.